# How to use mathfont with the family

Tags: fonts, math-mode

To be more specific i need **Arev font** in **math mode** using only the family fav or favm, but the way I did not work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% family
\newcommand{\fonte}[2]{
  {\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont #2}
}

\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Arev}

Math mode

\fonte{favm}{$f(t) = \frac{T}{2\pi} \int{\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\omega}{t}}}dt$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want that all math is in the Arev font?

Comment: Only in selected mathmode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be sufficient for the commonest formulas

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareMathVersion{arev}

% These are the predefined symbol alphabets.
\SetSymbolFont{operators}    {arev}{OT1}{zavm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}      {arev}{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}      {arev}{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols} {arev}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}

% These are the predefined math alphabets.
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathnormal}{arev}{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}    {arev}{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}    {arev}{OT1}{zavm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}    {arev}{OML}{zavm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}    {arev}{OT1}{zavm}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}    {arev}{T1} {fvm} {m}{n}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$f(t) = \frac{T}{2\pi} \int{\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\omega}{t}}}dt$

\mathversion{arev}
$f(t) = \frac{T}{2\pi} \int{\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\omega}{t}}}dt$

\end{document}
```

To go back to the normal setting issue `\mathversion{normal}` or put the Arev math in a group. Note that `\mathversion{arev}` must go *outside* the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
  \usepackage{arev}
  \usepackage{mathastext}
```

See your MWE with this options:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  \usepackage{arev}
  \usepackage{mathastext}

  \parindent=0pt
  \pagestyle{empty}

  \begin{document}

  \subsection*{Arev}

  Math mode

  $f(t) = \frac{T}{2\pi} \int{\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\omega}{t}}}dt$

  \end{document}
```

You can also explore mathastext package for more options.